# PHP MySQL Date Comparsion

Tags: php, mysql, date

I Have a Mysql with the rows Data1,data2,data3...Data7 and i want to compare with the current date,searching the internet i got this so far:

```
$curDate = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT Id FROM Programacao where Data1 = $curDate";
$result = mysql_query($query);   
if(!$result) {echo 'Nada';}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo "Id = ".$row ['Id'];
}
```

But i can read only the first one,does it possible to compare all of them at the same time?

Comment: You mean `Data1 = '$curDate'`, right?

Comment: "I Have a Mysql with the rows Data1,data2,data3...Data7" **cries**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use logic operators. If you need check that AT LEAST ONE of `Data` is `$curDate`

```
$query = "
SELECT Id 
FROM Programacao 
WHERE Data1 = $curDate 
   OR Data2 = $curDate
   OR Data3 = $otherDateIfYouNeedOther
";
```

You should replace `or` by `and` if you need to check that ALL OF THEM are OK.

Besides, As far as I remember You should use Date values in quotes, so correct one is

```
$query = "
SELECT Id 
FROM Programacao
WHERE Data1 = '$curDate'
   OR Data2 = '$curDate'
   OR Data3 = '$otherDateIfYouNeedOtherOrSameOtherwise'
";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id,CASE 
    WHEN  Data1 = CURDATE() then 'Data1'
    WHEN  Data2 = CURDATE() then 'Data2'
    WHEN  Data3 = CURDATE() then 'Data3'
    ELSE ''
END as Data_Table
FROM Programacao
WHERE Data1 = CURDATE()
   OR Data2 = CURDATE()
   OR Data3 = CURDATE()
....
```

Comment: [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: It worked,but i have another issue,i wanna know wich table has the correct data,in this case lets say its the "Data1" table,how i can know that?

Comment: Edited my answer, check if it helps you