# Timestamp Comparsion MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, comparison, timestamp

I´m trying to compare the rows, with the current date and hour,

```
    $curDate = date("Y-m-d H").':00:00';
    $query = "SELECT Id FROM Programacao WHERE Data1 = $curDate OR Data2 = $curDate OR Data3 = $curDate 
    OR Data4 = $curDate OR Data5 = $curDate OR Data6 = $curDate  OR Data7 = $curDate";

    $result = mysql_query($query);   
    if(!$result) {echo 'No program today';}
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['Id'];
    }
```

The row data in the database is like that: "2011-09-10 18:00:00"
But i always get : `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result` 
any corrections?

Comment: Something is wrong with your query. Place `echo mysql_error();` after your `mysql_query()` line. Alternatively you could `echo $query;` and attempt to run it yourself.

Comment: Didn't you just ask a question with code like this? Where'd it go?

Comment: @JohnD: Yes, is this it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457950/php-mysql-date-comparsion

Comment: @Craig A Rodway Yup, that's the one. Not sure why a new account was made for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

will give you error needed to know what is wrong

in your case, you've forgotten quotes around dates

this one is better and will probably work

```
$query = "SELECT Id FROM Programacao WHERE Data1 = '$curDate' OR Data2 = '$curDate' OR Data3 = '$curDate' 
OR Data4 = '$curDate' OR Data5 = '$curDate' OR Data6 = '$curDate'  OR Data7 = '$curDate'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes round your date literals in SQL:

```
"... WHERE Data1 = '$curDat' ..."
```

The resulting SQL should look like something like this:

```
... WHERE Data1 = '2010-12-17 15:00:00' ...
```